# How to configure ssh client to use private keys automatically

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I'm always running `ssh` with the `-i` parameter and it's a hassle to always type in the correct key for whatever host I'm connecting to.

Is there a config file or something (on Mac) to define which private key to use when connecting to a particular host?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, you want to create a `~/.ssh/config` file. That lets you define a shortcut name for a host, the username you want to connect as, and which key to use. Here's part of mine, with hostnames obfuscated:

```
Host tabs
     HostName tabs.com
     User     me
     IdentityFile       ~/.ssh/new_rsa

Host scm.company.com
     User       cap
     IdentityFile       ~/.ssh/git_rsa

Host project-staging
     HostName 50.56.101.167
     User     me
     IdentityFile       ~/.ssh/new_rsa
```

With this I can say, `ssh tabs` and get connected to host tabs.com as user `me`, with key `new_rsa`, as though I'd used `ssh me@tabs.com -i ~/.ssh/new_rsa`.

Comment: Also a good way to go if you don't want to use `ssh-agent` for whatever reason.

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. +1

Comment: Thanks. Maybe small addition it's worthwhile to menaion that private key files should have correct permissions like setuped like `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: right answer and a shortcut, very smooth

Answer (score 4):

SSH clients will typically use `~/.ssh/identity` (ssh v1) or one of`~/.ssh/id_rsa` or `~/.ssh/id_dsa` (v2) as the default private key.  You can change this in `~/.ssh/config` (the `IdentityFile` parameter - the `-i` option to SSH actually overrides this.  See `man ssh_config` for details).

If you have multiple private keys to deal with using `ssh-agent` is probably a better choice.
See `man ssh-agent` for more details.

Comment: +1 for describing the defaults and citing the man page.

Answer (score 1):

If you use different keys for different servers I don't think there is.

If you use a single key for all servers, just save it as `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, it will be used automatically.